# Is it OK to lock on System.Collections.Generic.List<t>?

Tags: c#

I have been reading about the syncroot element but I can't find it in the List type.
So how should the multithreading synchronization be done with the System.Collections.Generic.List<> type?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you can't find it is because it was [explicitly removed](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396399.aspx).  If it is really what you want to do, use a `SynchronizedCollection<T>` or create a dedicated synchronization object.  The best approach (in general) is to create a dedicated synchronization object, as Winston illustrates.

The essential problem with the `SyncRoot` property is that it provides a false sense of security -- it only handles a very narrow set of circumstances.  Developers often neglect synchronization for an entire logical operation, assuming that locking on `SyncRoot` is good enough.

You generally want to avoid locking on a type (`List<T>` in this case).  If, for example, you have two instances of your type, or another type were to also use a lock on `List<T>`, they would all competing for a single global lock.  Really, what you are trying to achieve is proper synchronization for a single object.

Answer (score 11):

Why do you want to lock on `List<T>` as opposed to your specific instance of a list?

It is often suggested that the best method of locking is to lock on a private object created solely for that purpose.

```
private readonly object myListLock = new object();

// Everywhere you access myList
lock(myListLock)
{
 // do stuff with myList
}
```

For a great guide to threading in C#, see this [Free E-Book (Threading in C#)](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joe Albahari.

Comment: I don't think he's wanting to lock on `List<T>`.  He's wanting to lock his `List<T>` instance using the ICollection.SyncRoot property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356596.aspx).

Comment: Indeed, that's what his post said. But the title of it leads me to believe that he was considering locking on List<T> as an alternative.

Comment: Why is this better than locking on the instance of the list?

Comment: Regarding: Why is this better than locking on the instance of the list? - If you lock to an instance "lock(myList)" of the list you use the lock if you do something like "myList = new List<T>". Locked would be the older instance.

Answer (score 7):

You have to cast the generic list to an `ICollection` like this:

```
using System.Collection; // required for ICollection
using System.Collection.Generic;
List<int> myIntList = new List<int>();
lock (((ICollection)myIntList).SyncRoot)
{
    // do your synchronized stuff here...
}
```

Keep in mind that this only synchronizes access to the elements of the generic list.  It does ***not*** synchronize access to the generic list variable, e.g., `myIntList`.  If you replace `myIntList` with a new list at some point, using `SyncRoot` will not be sufficient.  In that case, I would recommend creating a specific synchronization object that can be used for both synchronization scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is Yes, you can use an instance of the list as a synchronizing object:

```
private readonly List<string> list = new List<string>();

lock(list)
{
    // ...
}
```

So you don't have to use SyncRoot property. Moreover, [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot.aspx) states that

> For collections whose underlying store is not publicly available, the
>   expected implementation is to return the current instance.

i.e. in some cases SyncRoot property returns the collection object itself.

Also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12425979/355438) about SyncRoot.

FYI: I've never seen SyncRoot usages in production code. So I *suggest* you to use instance of any collection as a synchronizing object instead of it's SyncRoot property (as long as the collection is private).